# php echo only if variable is exist

Tags: php

I have two variables

```
<?php 
    $male = $_GET["male"];
    $female = $_GET["female"];  
 ?>
```

I'm trying to echo only if the variable is exist so I wrote this statement

```
<?php if ( $male && $female ) { ?>
    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $male; ?> & <?php echo $female; ?></h1>
<?php } elseif ( $male ) { ?>
    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $male; ?></h1>
<?php } elseif ( $female ) { ?>
    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $female; ?></h1>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h1>Weclome</h1>
<?php } ?>
```

But now when `$male` and `$female` exist
the elseif is also true, How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add not male and not female to the elseif. Like this:

```
<?php if ( $male && $female ) { ?>
    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $male; ?> & <?php echo $female; ?></h1>
<?php } elseif ( $male && !$female ) { ?>
    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $male; ?></h1>
<?php } elseif ( $female && !$male ) { ?>
    <h1>Welcome, <?php echo $female; ?></h1>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h1>Weclome</h1>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: OK, but I get also error when I'm defining the 2 variables, for example if the female is not exist I get:"Undefined index: female in .... "

Comment: Your problem already starts with `$male = $_GET["male"];`. If there is no GET parameter `male` you'll get an undefined index error.

Comment: OK, what is the suggestion? to use what?

Comment: My solution, obviously ;-) For your solution you should replace `$male = $_GET["male"];` by `$male = $_GET['male'] ?? null;` (see [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op) for a pre php7 version of that) and `$female = ...` correspondingly.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<h1>Welcome';
$sep = array(', ', ' &amp; ');
foreach (array('male', 'female') as $param) {
    if ( isset($_GET[$param]) ) {
        echo array_shift($sep), htmlentities($_GET[$param]);
    }
}
echo '</h1>';
```

Comment: Seems a bit like overkill but I've always thought overkill is underrated

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `isset()` to test if the variable exist or null

```
if(isset($male)&&isset($male)){
<h1>Welcome, <?php echo $male; ?> & <?php echo $female; ?></h1>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use implode. You can also throw in some error checking.

```
$greeting = array();
if (!empty($_GET["male"]))
    $greeting[] = $_GET["male"];
if (!empty($_GET["male"]))
    $greeting[] = $_GET["male"];

if (count($greeting) > 0)
    echo "<h1>Welcome, " . implode(" & ", $greeting) . "!</h1>";
else
    echo "<h1>Who's there?</h1>";
```